# Trying to append new columns in a numpy array using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I am trying to add new columns using the average of old columns, but I don't know how to loop through the columns from the weights array and append them to the class2 array.

```
class1 = weights[:,sort[popsize-1]]

for x in range(1,avgmating+1):
  new = (class1 + np.array(weights[:,sort[popsize - 1 -x]]))/2
  class2 = np.hstack((class2,new))

NameError: name 'class2' is not defined
```

How can I define Class2 and then add the "new" array to it in each iteration?

Comment: You can define `class2` before the loop with any of the [array creation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/routines.array-creation.html#ones-and-zeros) routines.

Comment: what are your variables in code? could you give us explanation or sample input/output on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(1,avgmating+1):
  new = (class1 + np.array(weights[:,sort[popsize - 1 -x]]))/2
  if x == 1:
    class2 = new
  else:
    class2 = np.hstack((class2,new))
```

That works but I'm sure there is a faster way...